# Python - how to rewrite zip with for cycle?

Tags: python

I have a code which compares two lists

```py
a=[10,20,30,40,50,60,40,45]
x=[10,50,5,100,15,60]
z=([i > j for i, j in zip(a[-len(x):], x)])
print(z)
```

I need to rewrite it in the following format but current wording
returns error. How to correct it?

```py
a=[10,20,30,40,50,60,40,45]
x=[10,50,5,100,15,60]
for i in range(a[-len(x):],x):
    if a[i]>x[i]:
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't include information about the error and your efforts to solve it so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you're using `range` incorrectly. `range` takes integer arguments while you're passing the array

```
....
start_range = -len(x)
for i in range(len(x)):
     if a[start_range]>x[i]:
        print('yes')
     else:
        print('no')
     start_range+=1
...
```

Now I'm not sure what is it you expect from the output since the first snippet returns `boolean` in an array while the second snippet would print out `yes` and `no` in separate lines.

However, you can build the logic around the above since the only problem was the loop range.